# How to delete files from Firebase Storage and Table View - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating a Customer Management app for iOS. I'm using Firebase Firestore and Storage.
There is a part of my app when the user can attach document to each customer. I upload and then download the file in local folder to be able to display the file name in a TableView and open with QLPreviewController.

I save the path and name of uploaded file in Firestore.

This is my code where I want to delete the file with swipe. This work only if i try to delete the first file in table view but if try to delete the third file for example it will delete the first.

I have try this but it doesn't work for me: [Swift Firestore - Delete Table Cell and Remove Document from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480661/swift-firestore-delete-table-cell-and-remove-document-from-firestore)

I know where my problem is because I display files from [fileURLs] that have local url and I try to delete files from another array [documentArray], but I don't know how to fix this problem.

What I'm trying to do inside swipe function is. 1: I take the path from firestore and delete the file in storage. 2: I delete the document in firestore that have the path, 3: I delete the file that is locally and remove if from the array.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return fileURLs.count
    }
    
    //Display the file name in the cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "documentListCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = fileURLs[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
       
        return cell
    }
    
    //Open the file on click
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        previewVC.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row
        navigationController?.pushViewController(previewVC, animated: true)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK: Swipe left to delete the document
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
     {
         let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { [self] (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
  
             let documentId = self.documentArray[indexPath.row]
             
             if documentId.id != nil && documentId.url != "" {

                 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
                 //Get the sotrage reference from firesore
                 let fileRef = storageRef.child(documentId.url)
                 //Delete the specific file in firestore
                 fileRef.delete { error in
                     if let error = error{
                         print("Error while deleting the document \(error)")
                     } else{
                         print("File deleted successfully")
                         //Delete the document from firestore
                         self.db.collection(K.FStore.customerCollectionName).document(self.documentListRef)
                             .collection(K.FStore.docCollectionName).document(documentId.id!).delete(){ err in
                             if let err = err {
                                 print("Error while deleting the document: \(err)")
                             } else {
                                 //Get the local file path
                                 let docsurl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                                 let tempDirPath = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("\(K.FStorage.documentFolderName)/\(self.documentListRef)/\(documentId.fileName)")
                                 do {
                                     //Delete the local file from path
                                     try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempDirPath)
                                 } catch  { print(error) }
                                 print("Document successfully deleted")

                                 //remove the file from the table
                                 self.fileURLs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                 tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                             }
                          }
                       }
                   }
                
             }
         })
         deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
         return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    }
}

extension DocumentListController: QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate{
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return fileURLs.count
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        return fileURLs[index] as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

This is how my database looks

[image]

Comment: I think we can help but some troubleshooting is needed since we don't know how the data is stored in code. I suggest adding a breakpoint to your code and try to delete something by swiping. Step through your code line by line examining vars and code execution along the way until you spot something unexpected. For example, when this line executes `let documentId = self.documentArray[indexPath.row` what's the result of documentId - is it what you expected? Does it contain the properties you need to delete the data? How about this `K.FStore.customerCollectionName`? What does that resolve to?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me in my problem, but after a lot of works and google finally i solved my problem. I will post the changes now in case someone have the same issue in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** This is how i managed to solve my issue for deleting files in Storage the reference in Firestore and the downloaded file also i remove from the table directly.

This help me: [Swift Firestore - Delete Table Cell and Remove Document from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480661/swift-firestore-delete-table-cell-and-remove-document-from-firestore)

```
    let localFileName = fileURLs[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
     var storageURL = ""
     db.collection(K.FStore.customerCollectionName).document(documentListRef)
         .collection(K.FStore.docCollectionName).whereField("fileName", isEqualTo: localFileName).getDocuments{ snapshot, error in
         if let error = error {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
         } else {
             for document in snapshot!.documents {
                 //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                 let data = document.data()
                 if  let url = data["url"] as? String{
                     storageURL = url
                 }
        if document.documentID != "" {

         let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
         //Get the sotrage reference from firesore
         let fileRef = storageRef.child(storageURL)
         //Delete the specific file in firestore
         fileRef.delete { error in
             if let error = error{
                 print("Error while deleting the document \(error)")
             } else{
                 print("File deleted successfully")
                 //Delete the document from firestore
                 self.db.collection(K.FStore.customerCollectionName).document(self.documentListRef)
                     .collection(K.FStore.docCollectionName).document(document.documentID).delete(){ err in
                     if let err = err {
                         print("Error while deleting the document: \(err)")
                     } else {
                         //Get the local file path
                         let docsurl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                         let tempDirPath = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("\(K.FStorage.documentFolderName)/\(self.documentListRef)/\(localFileName)")
                         do {
                             //Delete the local file from path
                             try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempDirPath)
                         } catch  { print(error) }
                         print("Document successfully deleted")
                         
                         //Remove the file from the TableView
                         self.fileURLs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                         tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```